# pdb prompt just exits without any interactive response

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, pdb

I am running a script **main.py**, which goes to a different function `tsv_image_conversion` if an `if` statement is correct, and in the `tsv_image_conversion` function, I save a `tsv` output from `pytesseract` and then try to use `pandas` to get values from the **tsv file**, but when I put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in my code, I am met with **pdb** exiting without any interactivity and also, if I am trying to print the values from the `dataframe` after some boolean masking, I don't get any print outputs or any errors.

P.S : I am using a **conda** environment named **ocr**.

Unable to understand why this is happening:

I am giving some code of `tsv_image_conversion` here:

```
def tsv_image_conversion(idx, start_word, end_word):
    with open('tsv_out.tsv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(pytesseract.image_to_data(Image.open(f'out{idx}.jpg')))

    print(os.getcwd())
    sdf = pd.read_csv('tsv_out.tsv', sep='\t')
    index1 = sdf[sdf['text'] == start_word].index.values[0]
    index2 = sdf[sff['text'] == end_word].index.values[0]
```

```
$ python main.py 
Index(['_id', 'backup', 'case_no', 'data_inserted_on', 'elastic', 'event_id',
       'link', 'md5', 'pdf_link', 'pdf_url', 'registration_date',
       'registration_location', 's3_pdf_link', 's_no', 'sisyphean_id',
       'status'],
      dtype='object')
1 md5: 5db95d6393cf281daf39079a
    /home/aspiring1/.Private/block_extraction/5db95d6393cf281daf39079a
> /home/aspiring1/.Private/block_extraction/5db95d6393cf281daf39079a/main.py(26)tsv_image_conversion()
(Pdb) 
(ocr) $Private/block_extraction$ vim +80 main.py
```

Comment: Almost sounds like your interpreter hits a bug and dies. Try https://github.com/alexmojaki/snoop. Basically `pip install snoop`, `import snoop`, then `@snoop` above `def tsv_image_conversion`.

Comment: @AlexHall : Can you explain more on what it means by : _my python interpreter hits a bug and dies_ .